# how to refresh a table row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to refresh a table row.when i click on refresh button it should refresh tr content.i am trying to achieve it using below code. but when i click on refresh button its refreshing but tr size decreased .it is like one td inside tr.how can i reload and how can  i see it like before.i will attach a pic where you can see whats happeing after reload

```
<tr id="sai">
....some data
</tr>

<button onclick="refresh()"> refresh</button>

function refresh(){
$('#sai').load('#sai')
}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  demo for this using jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept of refresh tr. What you want is changing tr innerHtml when clicking a button. I can't show exact code, since I don't know the content of the tr. However, your code will be something like this.

```
function refresh(){
    var newData = ...; // load from API or somewhere
    $('#sai').html('<td>' + newData + '</td>');
}
```

Comment: How can I get tr data . like document.getelementbyid(Sai)

Comment: When I tried the above code I didn't get the data of tr but it is showing table row element when I did alert for that document.getelementbyId("Sai")

Comment: You need to give me more info. Like what data you want to "refresh"? customer name? company address? AND how/where you get that data?